# How can I sort Reddit users by karma?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, sorting

I have a problem sorting the users based on their karma. Can you guys please help? (site: [here](https://karma-count.netlify.com/)) I want to sort the div elements of the users according to *totalKarma*. Also is there a good method for refreshing the data in the background so it doesn't have to load the whole page (like the user icons).

```js
var leaderboard = document.getElementById('leaderboard');
var commentKarma;
var postKarma;
var userName;
var userIcon;
var userUrl;
var usersloaded = [];
var userskarma = [];
var usersIcon = [];

var users = ['sloth_on_meth','filiptronicek','cigarkovic','gallowboob','tooshiftyforyou','actually_crazy_irl','haxpress'];

function updateStats() {
  leaderboard.innerHTML = '';
  users.forEach(mainfunc);
}
updateStats();

function mainfunc(user) {
  $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/user/' + user + '/about.json', function(data) {
      commentKarma = data.data.comment_karma;
      postKarma = data.data.link_karma;
      totalKarma = commentKarma + postKarma;
      userName = user;
      userIcon = data.data.icon_img;
      userUrl = 'https://reddit.com/u/' + userName;
      leaderboard.innerHTML +=
        "<div class='usr' id='" +
        userName +
        "'><br><br><img src='" +
        userIcon +
        "'><br><a href='" +
        userUrl +
        "'> u/" +
        userName +
        '</a><br>' +
        totalKarma.toLocaleString() +
        ' karma';

      usersloaded.push(user);
      userskarma.push(totalKarma);
      usersIcon.push(userIcon);

      // console.log(user);
      // console.log(usersIcon);
      userskarma.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      });
      
      // console.log(userskarma);
    })
    .done(function() {
      return;
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log('error loading ' + user);
    })
    .always(function() {
      // console.log('completed loading ' + user);
    });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.usr {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 4.5em;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
}

#leaderboard {
  width: 95%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#leaderboard>div {
  float: left;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff4500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="leaderboard">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @JuanMendes I know that but I didn’t know how to even attempt to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not attempting to rearrange the divs, it's just appending to the body as the requests come back. At a high level, you need to create an array of objects, sort them and print them after they have been sorted.

Note that I have made minimal changes to your code to get it working, but you would benefit from a code review

---

```js
var leaderboard = document.getElementById('leaderboard');
var commentKarma;
var postKarma;
var userName;
var userIcon;
var userUrl;
var usersloaded = [];
var userskarma = [];
var usersIcon = [];
users = [
  'sloth_on_meth',
  'filiptronicek',
  'cigarkovic',
  'gallowboob',
  'tooshiftyforyou',
  'actually_crazy_irl',
  'haxpress'
];

var userObjs = [];

function updateStats() {
  leaderboard.innerHTML = '';
  users.forEach(mainfunc);
}
updateStats();

function mainfunc(user) {
  $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/user/' + user + '/about.json', function(data) {
      commentKarma = data.data.comment_karma;
      postKarma = data.data.link_karma;
      totalKarma = commentKarma + postKarma;
      userName = user;
      userIcon = data.data.icon_img;
      userUrl = 'https://reddit.com/u/' + userName;
      userObjs.push({
        commentKarma,
        postKarma,
        totalKarma,
        userName,
        userIcon,
        userUrl
      });
      if (userObjs.length == users.length) {
        userObjs.sort((a, b) => a.totalKarma - b.totalKarma);
        leaderboard.innerHTML = userObjs.map(user => {
          return "<div class='usr' id='" +
            user.userName +
            "'><br><br><img src='" +
            user.userIcon +
            "'><br><a href='" +
            user.userUrl +
            "'> u/" +
            user.userName +
            '</a><br>' +
            user.totalKarma.toLocaleString() +
            ' karma';

        }).join("");

      }

      leaderboard.innerHTML +=
        "<div class='usr' id='" +
        userName +
        "'><br><br><img src='" +
        userIcon +
        "'><br><a href='" +
        userUrl +
        "'> u/" +
        userName +
        '</a><br>' +
        totalKarma.toLocaleString() +
        ' karma';

      usersloaded.push(user);
      userskarma.push(totalKarma);
      usersIcon.push(userIcon);

      console.log(user);
      console.log(usersIcon);
      userskarma.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      });
      console.log(userskarma);

      //setTimeout(function(){ updateStats(); }, 10000);
    })
    .done(function() {
      return;
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log('error loading ' + user);
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log('completed loading ' + user);
    });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

.usr {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 4.5em;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
}

#leaderboard {
  width: 95%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#leaderboard>div {
  float: left;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff4500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Reddit karma</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="leaderboard">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. Create an array `usersloaded` with user objects with `userName`, `userIcon`, `userUrl` etc properties. Then, it'll be easier for you sort the objects based on the `totalKarma` property and create the HTML as you're doing before.

```js
var leaderboard = document.getElementById('leaderboard');
var commentKarma;
var postKarma;
var userName;
var userIcon;
var userUrl;
var usersloaded = [];

users = [
  'sloth_on_meth',
  'filiptronicek',
  'cigarkovic',
  'gallowboob',
  'tooshiftyforyou',
  'actually_crazy_irl',
  'haxpress'
];

function updateStats() {
  leaderboard.innerHTML = '';
  users.forEach(mainfunc);
}
updateStats();

function mainfunc(user) {
  $.getJSON('https://www.reddit.com/user/' + user + '/about.json', function(data) {
      commentKarma = data.data.comment_karma;
      postKarma = data.data.link_karma;
      totalKarma = commentKarma + postKarma;
      userName = user;
      userIcon = data.data.icon_img;
      userUrl = 'https://reddit.com/u/' + userName;

      usersloaded.push({
        user,
        userName,
        userIcon,
        userUrl,
        totalKarma
      });

      loadData(usersloaded);

    })
    .done(function() {
      return;
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log('error loading ' + user);
    })
    .always(function() {
      //console.log('completed loading ' + user);
    });
}

function loadData(usersloaded) {
  leaderboard.innerHTML = ''
  usersloaded.sort((a, b) => a.totalKarma - b.totalKarma)
    .forEach(u => {
      leaderboard.innerHTML +=
        "<div class='usr' id='" +
        u.userName +
        "'><br><br><img src='" +
        u.userIcon +
        "'><br><a href='" +
        u.userUrl +
        "'> u/" +
        u.userName +
        '</a><br>' +
        u.totalKarma.toLocaleString() +
        ' karma';
    })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.usr {
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 4.5em;
  padding-bottom: 250px;
}

#leaderboard {
  width: 95%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#leaderboard>div {
  float: left;
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff4500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="leaderboard">
</div>
```